# Why do I get undefined for this Angular scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I use a factory to create objects for a particular module

```
angular.module("myModule").factory('MyEntity',
....
```

And the module accepts the generated 'MyEntity' as an injected dependency:

```
angular.module("myModule").controller('myProductCtrl', [
'$scope', 'MyEntity', '$rootScope', 'MyApiService'
 ...
```

The module has the following subscriber function that is used to subscribe the entity inside my module like this:

```
    MyEntity.subscribe(function(otherEntity) {

        $scope.myReference = otherEntity;

    });
```

At runtime, the above $scope.myReference is successfully assigned the expected object as it's value when the first module is loaded

... and I've now added this function onto the scope inside the same module:

```
    $scope.myModuleFunction = function (product) {
        if (myReference.yadda) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

... but the above '$scope' is undefined at the point that the function is called via the directive (in fact it's undefined once the web page has been displayed). Why might this be the case?

Comment: Have you added the $scope.myModuleFunction() in the myProductCtrl? Please refere to controller and factory when you use them instead of naming everything as module. Makes it easier to understand the setup here

Comment: Can you post the complete `directive` code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ($scope.myReference.yadda)`?

Comment: Thanks Episodex. The $scope was undefined in one particular context (something may have gone screwy somehow), and that problem went away after resetting the app and reloading. After altering that line to $scope.myReference, everything works